# Thumbnails Displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I am trying to retrieve thumbnails stored in folder and on clicking the new page will open to run video. Here is the code

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CellSpacing="5" 
        RepeatColumns="3" 
        Visible="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <u><%# Eval("videoTitle") %></u>
        <hr />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                ImageUrl='<%# Eval("thumbPath") %>'
                Height="200" 
                Width="200" 
                href='<%# Eval("videoId", "PlayVideo.aspx?videoId={0}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

On the code behind on page load

```
public void BindGrid()
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ToString();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select videoId, videoTitle,thumbPath from videoUpload";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            DataList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataList1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing two issues

1. The image is not displaying on ImageButton(or Image control)
2. on clicking the imagebutton an error is giving which is given below-

> Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
>   For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them.

Answer (score 0):

> The image is not displaying on ImageButton(or Image control)

Its because your **thumbpath** is wrong.

> on clicking the imagebutton an error is giving which is given below

Not getting into `EnableEventValidation` in this answer because `ImageButton` is not the Control to use here. Change it to

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"
        NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("videoId", "PlayVideo.aspx?videoId={0}") %>'>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"
        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("thumbPath") %>'
        Height="200"
        Width="200" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

On an unrelated side-note, do not use `u` tag. Its [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#edef-U).

Comment: Thanks this one is better. But on PlayVideo.aspx i am having issue. On this page two flow player running simultaneously with same video.